# Add trailing slash in csh

Tags: directory, autocomplete, csh

How do I get csh to add a trailing slash at the end of tab autocompletion?

eg: `\stuff \otherstuff`

now if I type `cd s` and press tab, I get: `\stuff` and not `\stuff\`

Comment: Are you using csh or tcsh? In tcsh there is the `addsuffix` option, which should actually be enabled by default.

Comment: @MartinTournoij The real `csh` does not have tab completion; when the `filec` variable is set, file competion is done with ESC (and ^D for listing multiple candidates). Anyways, it's not clear what the OP wants with all those **back**slashes. I've tried creating two files with spaces with `touch 'a b C' 'a b D'` and then `ls a<tab>` in **`tcsh`** will complete up to `ls a\ b\ ` and list the 2 files as expected.

Comment: csh
@mosvy eg are folders. The idea is to breeze through a directory tree by just entering the first character(s) [Tab] [Enter] first character(s)[Tab][Enter]. Currently I would need to type in / between the tab and enter

Comment: What does `set | grep -E 'shell|version|addsuffix|autoexpand'` *and* `ls -F` in that directory show? (please do not answer in comments, but edit the info into your question)